# Monitor a process (everything)

Tags: c++, linux, process, monitor

I want to monitor a process and everything it does (every signal it gives SIGINT what ever).

Is there anyway to do this?

I'm using Linux (Ubuntu 11 to be exact)

Comment: Just as an added info, you can use [SeaLion](http://sealion.com) as a realtime monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) unix command will do all that and more if you're looking for command-line monitoring.

It uses the [ptrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace) system call infrastructure for monitoring which is in itself even more powerful: additionally allowing control of and interaction with the process. To quote from Wikipedia:

> ptrace is used by debuggers (such as gdb and dbx), by tracing tools like strace and ltrace, and by code coverage tools. ptrace is also used by specialised programs to patch running programs, to avoid unfixed bugs or to overcome security features. It can further be used as a sandbox and as a runtime environment simulator (like emulating root access for non-root software).

If you want to do this monitoring programatically rather than from the command line, then ptrace is the solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

[strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) ought to work, or something listed in the "Other Tools" section on that page.